# How to get and change encoding schema for a DB2 z/OS database using dynamic SQL statement

Tags: db2

A DB2 for z/OS database has been setup for me. Now I want to know the encoding scheme of the database and change it to Unicode if the database is other type of encoding.

How can I do this? Can I do this using dynamic SQL statements in my Java application?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify that the encoding scheme is UNICODE when you are creating your table (and database and tablepsace) by using the CCSID UNICODE clause.

According to the documentation:

> By default, the encoding scheme of a table is the same as the encoding scheme of its table space. Also by default, the encoding scheme of the table space is the same as the encoding scheme of its database. You can override the encoding scheme with the CCSID clause in the CREATE TABLESPACE or CREATE TABLE statement. However, all tables within a table space must have the same CCSID.

For more, see [Creating a Unicode Table](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db29.doc.char/db2z_createunicodetable.htm) in the [DB2 for z/os documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/topic/com.ibm.db29.doc/db2prodhome.htm).

You are able to create tables via Java/JDBC, but I doubt that you will be able to create databases and tablespaces that way.  I wouldn't recommend it anyway, I would find your closest z/os DBA and get that person to help you.

Comment: Thanks Michael. This is very helpful. One more question, is there any side effects to create and use Unicode tables in a non-Unicode database?

Comment: I don't think so, the only side effect I can think of is that you will need two separate tablespaces for the two sets of Unicode and non-Unicode tables

Comment: From DB2 document I found there might be another way to do this by using the "SET CURRENT APPLICATION ENCODING SCHEME" SQL statement. But the document also says "This statement can be embedded only in an application program. It is an executable statement that cannot be dynamically prepared." What does the *application program* really mean here and is it possible to use the statement in a JDBC application? Thanks.

Comment: Bruce I'm not really an expert but I think that statement is used to ensure that when you do inserts and updates of character data from your application, the character data uses the proper encoding scheme.

Comment: @Michael, and how to check the current CCSID setting for the database?